# Highcharts plotBands and plotLines default options in Highcharts.setOption()

Tags: highcharts

I created a simple theme and changed the fonts (size, family, color) on a lot of places, but can't find a way to change the font for plotband labels using `Highcharts.SetOptions()`. Is there a way style the plotbands this way?

Below is the code I'm currently using.

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['red',
    '#434348',
    '#90ed7d',
    '#f7a35c',
    '#8085e9',
    '#f15c80',
    '#e4d354',
    '#8085e8',
    '#8d4653',
    '#91e8e1'
  ],
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    reflow: true,
  },
  title: {
    style: {
      color: '#333',
      font: '18px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
    }
  },
  subtitle: {
    style: {
      color: '#666666',
      font: 'bold 12px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    itemStyle: {
      font: 'bold 12px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
      color: '#333',
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
      color: 'gray'
    },
    symbolRadius: 0
  },
  tooltip: {
    style: {
      font: '12px  "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSize: '12px'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#606060',
        font: '11px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
      },
      distance: 8
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
   labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#606060',
        font: '11px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
      }
    },
    title: {
      style: {
        color: '#606060',
        font: '12px  "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: '12px'
        }
      }
    }
  },
});



Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
      color: '#FCFFC5',
      from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),
      to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4),
      label: {
        text: 'Plot band',

      }
    }],
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 56.4, 69.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Hope someone can tell me how to solve this. It would be a shame if a have to add it to every plotband for every chart.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, by default, it is not possible to set default values for `plotLines` and `plotBands`, but I managed to make a simple function that adds default settings to them when loading the chart based on custom properties in `Highcharts.setOptions()`;

```js
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Chart, 'load', function() {
  const chart = this;

  function setDefaultOptions(axis) {
    const plotBandsOptions = [],
      plotLinesOptions = [];

    axis.plotLinesAndBands.forEach(function(plot) {
      if (plot.options.from) {
        plotBandsOptions.push(
          Highcharts.merge(chart.options.plotBands, plot.options)
        )
      } else {
        plotLinesOptions.push(
          Highcharts.merge(chart.options.plotLines, plot.options)
        )
      }
    })

    axis.update({
      plotBands: plotBandsOptions,
      plotLines: plotLinesOptions
    }, false);
  }

  chart.xAxis.forEach(function(axis) {
    setDefaultOptions(axis)
  });
  chart.yAxis.forEach(function(axis) {
    setDefaultOptions(axis)
  });
  chart.redraw();
});


Highcharts.setOptions({
  plotBands: {
    color: 'red',
    label: {
      text: 'Test'
    }
  },
  plotLines: {
    color: 'red',
    label: {
      text: 'Test'
    }
  },
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sjd048b9/